# Shutting down a frozen iPad with broken sleep button

Tags: ipad, performance

My iPad is frozen. I have Assistive Touch enabled. I can touch some buttons in AssistiveTouch, but I can't shut it down. The sleep button on the device is broken too.

Answer (score 3):

Let it use up all the charge on the battery. Then it shuts down automatically, and you can charge it to use it again.